# facebook-graph-api , array list and duplicates

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of event ids `eid1,eid2,eid3....` The creator of these events have a user id of `uid1,uid1,uid2,...`   Multiple event ids can have the same user id. Now I am trying to get the name of the user associated with the user id. It is to be noted that the order uid1,uid1,uid2,... is important since my ultimate aim is to get the user creator name for  each event id.

If i query facebook:
select name from user where uid in (uid1,uid1,uid2)

it returns

```
username1
username2
```

But I need it to return

```
username1
username1
username2
```

So that I can match it up with my event id later and display it in a list view.

I have also tried select name,host from event where eid in (select eid from event_member where uid=me() but the host seems to always be null. Is there any way out of this?

Comment: save your list. create a new list (or map) with unique uids. get answers from from facebook per unique uid. use your original list to arrange the answers.

Comment: I think I will try that out.Look like my only option

Comment: Yep. That worked. Please post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save your list. create a new list (or map) with unique uids. get answers from from facebook per unique uid. use your original list to arrange the answers.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `Collection` framework.
- If order/sequence is important then use `List`.

For example:

```
List<String> arList =          // put your response here
```